# More general way to find if a type has a certain member?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to make something that'll tell me if a type has a certain function / variable at compile time. I'm aware there's solutions posted, but these all require copy-pasting or macros for every distinct check. I'm wondering if there's a more general way to do this.

Maybe with syntax like:

`bool has_certain_member = has<type, member>::value;`

as opposed to:

```
DEFINE_MEMBER_CHECK(member)

bool has_certain_member = CHECK_FOR_MEMBER(type);
```

Where DEFINE_MEMBER_CHECK defines a helper type to check for that specific member and CHECK_FOR_MEMBER gets the value for a certain type.

Is there a way to pass a pointer to member as a template argument? Or maybe you'd pass it as an argument to a constexpr function?

Comment: You'd need reflection for that. We currently don't have reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `is_detected` is for

```
#include<experimental/type_traits>

template<typename T>
using foo_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());

template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_foo = std::experimental::is_detected_v<foo_t, T>;
```

And use it as

```
struct Fooer { void foo() {} };
struct Barer { void bar() {} };

void test()
{
    static_assert(has_foo<Fooer>);
    static_assert(!has_foo<Barer>);
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/hUAdGu)

Comment: I think this is what OP already knew. From question: **I'm aware there's solutions posted, but these all require copy-pasting or macros for every distinct check.**. I don't think this solution can get rid of repetition.

Comment: @liliscent This is about as little repetition as possible given the flexibility of what it does. The snippet above is asking if there is some function `foo` that accepts no argument, you would have to write that specification _somewhere_. Wrapping it up in macros pretty much gives what the OP asked for in the latter half

Comment: The answer should be *no way*. Please read OP's post carefully, especially **"as opposed to:"** that part, your answer is exactly the opposite of requirement.

Comment: @liliscent I read that as: "the latter half has the right functionality but is macros". There is no macros here

Comment: yep I beleive this is as simple as this is going to get. Thank you!